# piwik error while request data in a daterange

Tags: matomo

i have a problem for getting reports in piwik from a date range about 30 days on dashboard , visitors and actions tabs. when i want to do this this error occures :

Oops… there was a problem during the request. Maybe the server had a temporary issue, or maybe you requested a report with too much data. Please try again. If this error occurs repeatedly please contact your Piwik administrator for assistance.

i did archiving with below command :

/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/piwik/console core:archive --url=http://myip/piwik/
and it resolved issue just on dashboard , and it still show that error when i want to get reports for a date range about 30 days on visitors and actions tabs.
when i set the date range to smaller ranges for example about 15 days it is ok and does not shows any error.
i have installed piwik on RHEL with php 5.3.3 and mysql 5.1 .
can anyone help me how to fix this problem.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i increased memory_limit from 128M to 512M and max_execution_time from 30 to 120 in my php.ini and the issue resolved.
this may be useful for someone with same problem.
thanks

Comment: I work for Matomo (formerly Piwik).
On the very large sites (10M to 200M hits per month) Matomo has been advising users to set the PHP memory to 2G or even 8G

Update your php.ini file to increase your memory limit in the file
/etc/php/cli/php.ini
and/or at
/etc/php/apache/php.ini

To give Matomo enough memory to process your web analytics reports, increase the memory limit to 2g
memory_limit = 2G

You can learn more in: https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/#increase-php-memory-limit

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed this issue. It is related with data format. After changing the date format, i could able to load my page with out issue. I have added the error.log for the reference.

Hope this will help to someone who is seeking help.

You can change the particular table column "date format" by using the below query:

UPDATE `table_name`
SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')

[Sat Sep 12 12:03:37.124105 2015] [:error] [pid 21414] [client 192.168.1.22:50006] Error in Piwik: Date format must be: YYYY-MM-DD, or 'today' or 'yesterday' or any keyword supported by the strtotime function (see http://php.net/strtotime for more information): -62169984000, referer: http://192.168.1.20/AP_Enterprise/index.php?module=MultiSites&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means, that there was a timeout. Try to adjust your configs. The reason for timeouts is the fact, that date range reports are not pre-archived.

On the other hand, it's recommended to use PHP 5.4+ and MySQL 5.5+ if the performance is important for you.